# How to drag nodes in same level on treeview c#?

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, treeview, nodes

i need drag nodes in same level on treeview c#, im trying but not working.

```
-Node  
   --First  
   --Second  
   --Third  
   --Four  

-Node  
   --Second  
   --First  
   --Four  
   --Third
```

Only have one level in treeview i need realign nodes.
Sorry my english level, i hope you can help me.

```
private void ArmaArbol()
{
    try
    {
        this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        CTareas mngtar = new CTareas();
        var Tareas = mngtar.ObtieneTodasTareas();

        tvTareas.BeginUpdate();
        tvTareas.Nodes.Clear();

        TreeNode nodoTareas = new TreeNode();
        nodoTareas.Name = "1";
        nodoTareas.Text = "Tareas 5's";
        tvTareas.Nodes.Add(nodoTareas);

        foreach (var tarea in Tareas)
        {
            TreeNode nodoTarea = new TreeNode();
            nodoTarea.Text = tarea.Tar_Descripción;
            nodoTarea.Name = tarea.Id_Tar.ToString();
            tvTareas.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(nodoTarea);
        }
        tvTareas.EndUpdate();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        Sistema.MensajeError("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should show your code so we can see what you've tried.

Comment: Ok, you can help me please.